# Video Analysis using Sikuli

Tags: video, automation, sikuli

I wanted to know if Sikuli can be helpful in video analysis. I have captured a video of users testing a prototype. I want to analyze the video when any clicks or UI changes are made.

Have anyone used this approach or is it possible with Sikuli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my personal experience with Sikuli I think it is practically impossible. Sikuli operates by finding patterns on a screen by scanning it and returning the best match (based on defined settings). This comparison takes time and I am certain it will be of no use trying to inspect a video, which is essentially a very fast changing pattern.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene.. Is there anything else which I can use?

Comment: @Tilak Unfortunately not. And to be frank with you I doubt such software exists. It will be really hard to visually monitor a video stream.